# Emacs linum-mode using the Solarized theme doesn't show correct font size for org-mode headings

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a problem with linum font scale. 
It would be great if linum scale saved current font size.

in my .emacs:

```
 (require 'linum)
 (setq linum-format "%4d ")
 (global-linum-mode 1)
 (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Source Code Pro Medium-14"))
 (set-default-font "Source Code Pro Medium-14")
```

I was trying to use this instruction: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc8
but didn't have the result.

[frame] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/whO3Q.png

help!

I thought the problem was with linum-mode. But later it turned out that I forgot to turn on (setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil) to make letters in headers smaller.

Comment: Try checking this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29786/font-size-issues-with-emacs-in-linum-mode

Comment: Thank you. Problem hasn't solved but I'll have been using face-attribute

Comment: Is that specific font an integral part of the question/problem?  I don't have that font, and I cannot replicate the issue in your screenshot with that init file (in Emacs 25.2). All my line numbers are the same font size as the rest of the text on that line. (Are you actually testing with only that config?)

Comment: I found the reason of this problem. It's been my solarized theme. github page have an instruction how to fix this problem. Sorta (setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)

Comment: @Nonull, please edit your question so that it incorporates the actual source of the issue (because the config you've posted appears to be largely irrelevant), and then post an Answer with the solution you've discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this problem. It's been my solarized theme. github page have an instruction how to fix this problem. Sorta.

```
(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)
```

Comment: Could you also link to the instructions in question?